# How to filter db data based on a JSONB column in KNEX using Typescript / Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, knex.js, jsonb

Please help point me in the right direction: I have a jsonb column in one of my tables. It saves stringified data like this:

```
entry: {
    1: "data1",
    2: "data2"
}
```

If I want to get entries whose key 1 is data1, how do I write the query?
Below throws an sql error:

```
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['1'] = 'data1' limit 500' at line 1",
```

Here is what I used in the model:

```
return await db(db_table).select('*')
.limit(per_page).where('form_id', form_id)
.whereRaw("entry->>[?] = ?",['1', 'data1']); // issue is here
```

How can I construct that last line to search json field/column and return all filtered rows in the table where key 1 is equal to data1?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```js
return await db(db_table).select('*')
  .limit(per_page).where('form_id', form_id)
  .whereRaw("entry->>$.?? = ?",['1', 'data1']); // issue is here
  // ------------------^ this extra ? marks a placeholder for a column
```

Comment: I'll definitely try this out and get back you. Thank you for taking a moment to look at my question, means a lot  :)

Comment: @felixmosh please if I have sql jsonb column in db named `'car'` with structure `[{'brand':'audi', 'year':'2001'}]`   --> to filter WHERE brand=audi will be:
 `return await db(db_table).select('*').whereRaw("car->>$.?? = ?",['brand', 'audi']);`  ? thx

Comment: It won't work since you have an object inside an array, please open a new question, and tag me... I will try to answer

Comment: oki, done. thank you https://stackoverflow.com/q/73415051/10072357