# knex json object WHERE condition

Tags: sql, knex.js

I have sql jsonb column in db named 'car' with structure
[{'brand':'audi', 'year':'2001'}] --> how to filter WHERE brand=audi?

this doesn't seem to be right:

```js
return await db(db_table)
  .select('*')
  .whereRaw('car->>$.?? = ?', ['brand', 'audi']);
```

@felixmosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your object is an array of objects, your suggested code won't work.

Try something like this:

```js
return await db(db_table)
  .select('*')
  .whereRaw('car->>$[0].?? = ?', ['brand', 'audi']);
  // ----------------^ this selects the first element of the array
```